# How to override names of dataclasses attributes in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-dataclasses

I am using `dataclass` to parse (HTTP request/response) JSON objects and today I came across a problem that requires *transformation/alias* attribute names within my classes.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import List
import json


@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo_name: str # foo_name -> FOO NAME


@dataclass
class Bar:
    bar_name: str # bar_name -> barName


@dataclass
class Baz:
    baz_name: str # baz_name -> B A Z
    baz_foo: List[Foo] # baz_foo -> BAZ FOO
    baz_bar: List[Bar] # baz_bar -> BAZ BAR
```

currently:

```py
# encode
baz_e = Baz("name", [{"foo_name": "one"}, {"foo_name": "two"}], [{"bar_name": "first"}])
json_baz_e = json.dumps(asdict(baz_e))
print(json_baz_e)
# {"baz_name": "name", "baz_foo": [{"foo_name": "one"}, {"foo_name": "two"}], "baz_bar": [{"bar_name": "first"}]}


# decode
json_baz_d = {
    "baz_name": "name", 
    "baz_foo": [{"foo_name": "one"}, {"foo_name": "two"}], 
    "baz_bar":[{"bar_name": "first"}]
}
baz_d = Baz(**json_baz_d) # back to class instance
print(baz_d)
# Baz(baz_name='name', baz_foo=[{'foo_name': 'one'}, {'foo_name': 'two'}], baz_bar=[{'bar_name': 'first'}])
```

expected:

```py
# encode
baz_e = Baz("name", [{"FOO NAME": "one"}, {"FOO NAME": "two"}], [{"barName": "first"}])
json_baz_e = json.dumps(asdict(baz_e))


# decode
json_baz_d = {
    "B A Z": "name", 
    "BAZ FOO": [{"FOO NAME": "one"}, {"FOO NAME": "two"}], 
    "BAZ BAR":[{"barName": "first"}]
}
baz_d = Baz(**json_baz_d) # back to class instance
```

Is the only solution [dataclasses-json](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json#encode-or-decode-using-a-different-name), or is there still a possibility without additional libraries?

Answer (score 7):

You could certainly use `dataclasses-json` for this, however if you don't need the advantage of *marshmallow* schemas, you can probably get by with an alternate solution like the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/), which is similarly a JSON serialization library built on top of dataclasses.  It supports *alias* field mappings as needed here; another bonus is that it doesn't have any dependencies outside of Python stdlib, other than the `typing-extensions` module for Python < 3.10.

There's a [few choices](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/custom_key_mappings.html) available to specify *alias* field mappings, but in the below example I chose two options to illustrate:

- `json_field`, which can be considered an alias to `dataclasses.field`
- a `json_key_to_field` mapping that can be specified in the Meta config for a dataclass

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard, json_field


@dataclass
class Foo:
    # pass all=True, so reverse mapping (field -> JSON) is also added
    foo_name: str = json_field('FOO NAME', all=True)


@dataclass
class Bar:
    # default key transform is `camelCase`, so alias is not needed here
    bar_name: str


@dataclass
class Baz(JSONWizard):

    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        json_key_to_field = {
            # Pass '__all__', so reverse mapping (field -> JSON) is also added
            '__all__': True,
            'B A Z': 'baz_name',
            'BAZ FOO': 'baz_foo',
            'BAZ BAR': 'baz_bar'
        }

    baz_name: str
    baz_foo: List[Foo]
    baz_bar: List[Bar]


# encode
baz_e = Baz("name", [Foo('one'), Foo('two')], [Bar('first')])
json_baz_d = baz_e.to_dict()

print(json_baz_d)
# {'B A Z': 'name', 'BAZ FOO': [{'FOO NAME': 'one'}, {'FOO NAME': 'two'}], 'BAZ BAR': [{'barName': 'first'}]}

# decode
baz_d = Baz.from_dict(json_baz_d)  # back to class instance

print(repr(baz_d))
# > Baz(baz_name='name', baz_foo=[Foo(foo_name='one'), Foo(foo_name='two')], baz_bar=[Bar(bar_name='first')])

# True
assert baz_e == baz_d
```

---

*NB*: I noticed one obvious thing that I wanted to point out, as it seemed to not result in expected behavior. In the question above, you appear to be instantiating a `Baz` instance as follows:

```
baz_e = Baz("name", [{"foo_name": "one"}, {"foo_name": "two"}], [{"bar_name": "first"}])
```

However, note that the value for the `baz_foo` field, in this case, is a list of Python `dict` objects rather than a list of `Foo` instances. To fix this, in above solution I've changed the `{"foo_name": "one"}` for example to `Foo('one')`.

Comment: In addition to installing an additional library, and limiting to versions, for a large project such as a larger number of classes and a number of attributes (as in my example) your mapping would turn into a complex solution. And I wrote the last part well - on request. :) . If there is no more elegant solution, complex will be acceptable.

Comment: I unfortunately don't know of an elegant solution using builtin modules in Python. I know that there some great validation libraries like [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), however even those require you to use a `BaseModel` or their own version of the `@dataclass` decorator, and also define alias mappings using `Field`. In that regards, I feel like this is a pretty elegant solution by itself, however there's likely a simpler solution with another library, or a better way that I haven't thought of myself.

Comment: Also, note that the `Baz(**json_baz_d)` wouldn't work in the original example above, unless you're using a model like from `pydantic` which overrides the constructor method; the reason is that this appears to be a nested dataclass model, and the inner `dict` objects unfortunately aren't converted by default.

Comment: I elegantly think that it is clean code that would be easily applied in more complicated, ie on a larger project, because the problem you have presented is just a simple presentation of the problem.  That's right, one of the solutions is that the `@dataclass_json` decorator with `field(metadata=config(field_name ="overriddenGivenName"))` has already mentioned.

Comment: @MilovanTomašević If possible, could you elaborate on what a larger example of the problem is? If there are a lot of dataclass fields and the *key transform* is very deterministic (for ex. snake_case to TitleCase) there might be a way to specify such a transform func and avoid defining field *alias* mappings as in this case.

Comment: That's right, the idea is great and the problem is in the large number of attributes where every key of a different standard is a problem. Imagine 500 attributes where snake_case, camelCase, PascalCase and even some non-standard type are required. I have no idea how a function or decorator would detect all the requirements but I like your idea.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the solution with `dataclasses-json` makes the code more readable and cleaner.

```sh
pip install dataclasses-json
```

This [library](https://lidatong.github.io/dataclasses-json/) provides a simple API for encoding and decoding [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to and from JSON.

```py
import json
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field
from dataclasses_json import config, dataclass_json


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo_name: str = field(metadata=config(field_name="FOO NAME")) # foo_name -> FOO NAME


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Bar:
    bar_name: str = field(metadata=config(field_name="barName")) # bar_name -> barName


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Baz:
    baz_name: str = field(metadata=config(field_name="B A Z")) # baz_name -> B A Z
    baz_foo: List[Foo] = field(metadata=config(field_name="BAZ FOO")) # baz_foo -> BAZ FOO
    baz_bar: List[Bar] = field(metadata=config(field_name="BAZ BAR")) # baz_bar -> BAZ BAR


# encode
baz_e = Baz("name", [{"FOO NAME": "one"}, {"FOO NAME": "two"}], [{"barName": "first"}])
print(baz_e.to_dict())
# {'B A Z': 'name', 'BAZ FOO': [{'FOO NAME': 'one'}, {'FOO NAME': 'two'}], 'BAZ BAR': [{'barName': 'first'}]}


# decode
json_baz_d = {
    "B A Z": "name", 
    "BAZ FOO": [{"FOO NAME": "one"}, {"FOO NAME": "two"}], 
    "BAZ BAR":[{"barName": "first"}]
}
baz_d = Baz.from_dict(json_baz_d) # back to class instance
print(baz_d)
# Baz(baz_name='name', baz_foo=[Foo(foo_name='one'), Foo(foo_name='two')], baz_bar=[Bar(bar_name='first')])


# Mini test
test_from_to = Baz.from_json(baz_e.to_json())
print(test_from_to)
# Baz(baz_name='name', baz_foo=[Foo(foo_name='one'), Foo(foo_name='two')], baz_bar=[Bar(bar_name='first')])

test_to_from = Baz.to_json(test_from_to)
print(test_to_from)
# {"B A Z": "name", "BAZ FOO": [{"FOO NAME": "one"}, {"FOO NAME": "two"}], "BAZ BAR": [{"barName": "first"}]}
```

##### Encode or decode from camelCase (or kebab-case)?

- JSON letter case by convention is camelCase, in Python members are by convention snake_case.
- You can configure it to encode/decode from other casing schemes at both the class level and the field level.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import LetterCase, config, dataclass_json


# changing casing at the class level
@dataclass_json(letter_case=LetterCase.CAMEL)
@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo_bar: str
    foo_baz: str


f = Foo('one', 'two').to_json() 
print(f)
# {"fooBar": "one", "fooBaz": "two"}


# at the field level
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo_bar: str = field(metadata=config(letter_case=LetterCase.CAMEL))
    foo_baz: str


f = Foo('one', 'two').to_json() 
print(f)
# {"fooBar": "one", "foo_baz": "two"}

ff = Foo.from_json(f)
print(ff)
# Foo(foo_bar='one', foo_baz='two')
```

Note:

- In case of error:

```sh
ImportError: cannot import name '_TypedDictMeta' from 'typing_extensions'
```

> You probably have an older version of typing-extensions, it is necessary to update it to the latest one.

```sh
pip install typing-extensions -U
```